# Creating a custom control with a UserControl and DepenencyProperties using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I've created an MVVM UserControl that does what I want, but I'm wanting to add a DependencyProperty that will give me some more flexibility. (If a DependencyProperty is the best route.)

Basically, I want to add this functionality...

```
<!-- Before -->
<local:MyCustomControl />

<!-- After -->
<local:MyCustomControl IsMasterControl="True" />
```

I've added the following DependencyProperty in MyCustomControlViewModel:

```
public bool IsMasterControl
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMasterControlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsMasterControlProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMasterControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsMasterControl", typeof(bool), typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

However, when I try to add that attribute to my control in XAML I don't get the option to add IsMasterControl.

What could I be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: "*I've added the following DependencyProperty in MyCustomControlViewModel*" - really? It looks like you've added it to your MyCustomControl.  And that's exactly where it belongs. Besides that, a custom control should not have its own "private" view model. Instead it should expose dependency properties that are bound to properties of an "external" view model that is passed to its DataContext from its parent element, e.g. a Window.

Comment: The DepencencyProperty is declared in the ViewModel, which is where I thought everything should be declared to satisfy MVVM but I'm also fairly new to MVVM.

Should a custom control be made up entirely of dependency properties with no ViewModel? I guess I'm not understanding how to best approach setting this up.

Comment: The dependency property must be declared in the control. As said, a control should not have something like its own view model. That's not what MVVM is about. Take a look at [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview).

Comment: @Clemens I was going to rebutt the "private VM" thing as I've seen that before but you know what? You convinced me after thinking about it again.  _I learnt something new today_. :)  I would upvote your first comment but it won't let me so I did your last one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it makes sense to define DP in a ViewModel, DP are considered part of the presentation.  Generally you define them in the View specifically in the *code-behind*.  Views and DP might exist even before the VM does. (might be important for DP hierarchies too).

Now if you really want it in the VM (say as regular C# properties), you still need to expose DP in the view's code-behind.  You'll need to keep both in sync.  When say the DP changes handle the change event and inform the VM and vice-versa.

Comment: I'm fairly new to MVVM but isn't one of the big no-nos to never put code in the code-behind?

Comment: @n0kx that’s a common misconception.  Also a DP has nothing to do with MVVM.  Want a DP?  It has to go in the code-behind